# appendTimestamp and registerAssetBundle

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am using the following configurations to add the timestamp in the assets path via asset manager.

```
'assetManager' => [
      'appendTimestamp' => true,
```

appAsset.php

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{   
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        '/css/style.css'
    ];
}
```

In view

```
AppAsset::register($this);
```

But in html I still see `'/css/style.css'` without timestamp.

I saw solution 
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/9101#issuecomment-267274327

```
$file = '/css/style.css';
$asset = new \yii\web\AssetBundle(
    [
        'js' => [ltrim($file, '/')],
        'basePath' => '@webroot',
        'baseUrl' => '/'
    ]
);
$this->getAssetManager()->bundles[$file] = $asset;
$this->registerAssetBundle($file);
```

This example is work. `'/css/style.css?v=12557565'`

Is there any method write registerAssetBundle() not in a view files?

Comment: why are you defining `public $sourcePath = '@frontend/assets';` ?

Comment: my mistake. I removed it

Comment: i edited the answer please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, what is `public $sourcePath = '@frontend/assets';`? it is not the correct path this path actually has your `Asset.php` files, not the source files. According to the documentation

> `sourcePath`: specifies the root directory that contains the asset
>   files in this bundle. **This property should be set if the root
>   directory is not Web accessible. Otherwise, you should set the
>   `basePath` property and `baseUrl`, instead**. Path aliases can be used here.

Just place your `.css` files under `frontend/web/css`  and `.js` under `frontend/web/js` and remove the `sourcePath` you do not need it as looking at your code, only in case if you had your source files under `frontend/themes/basic` then you would use `sourcePath` like `public $sourcePath = '@frontend/themes/basic/';` because this path isnt under the `web` accessable directory

And for adding the timestamp You do not have to do anything other than adding the `appendTimestamp` options under the `components` section in the `assetManager`, make sure you are adding `assetManager`  under components. and it will automatically start adding `?v=125453612` with all `CSS` and `js` files

your `AppAsset.php`

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{   
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/style.css'
    ];
}
```

`frontend/config/main.php`

```
'components' => [
..........
..........
    'assetManager' => [
        'appendTimestamp' => true
    ]
..........
..........
],
```

and your file will start looking like this

[image]

I can show you a live example of the same site if you want to have a look into the view-source

---

**EDIT**

As you provided the source code screen grab and looking at your code I can tell that you are using trailing slash `/` with your files, remove the trailing slashes from your source files path, I also overlooked it the first glance but then looking the code i couldn't find any other thing than this one that could be wrong. they should be like this

```
'css/new.css',
'css/new2.css',
```

and same for the `js` files too.

Comment: I see timestamps for predefied  'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' bundles but not for mine

Comment: where are your files residing and have you included your files in the `AppAsset.php` file or created your own custom asset file? @Alexufo , share your complete code .

Comment: I attached a screenshot.

Comment: OMG. I knew it was must be deadly simple. THANK  YOU

Comment: haha, i also didn't noticed it until I replicated everything according to your image and the same results came as it was for you and as soon I removed the `/` it started working. cheers !

Answer (score 1):

Try write `public $css` and `public $js` without forst slash ("js/.." instead "/js/..").