# Yii2 doesn't link styles

Tags: css, yii2, assets

I want to use styles located at web/css and web/js using AppAsset.php. Here's the snippet from the top of my layout/main.php:

```
<?php


AppAsset::register($this);
?>
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">
<head>
    <meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <?php $this->registerCsrfMetaTags() ?>
    <title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
    <?php $this->head() ?>
```

And here's my AppAsset.php:

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        "css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "css/prettyPhoto.css",
        "css/price-range.css",
        "css/animate.css",
        "css/main.css",
        "css/responsive.css"
    ];
    public $js = [
        "js/jquery.js",
        "js/bootstrap.min.js",
        "js/jquery.scrollUp.min.js",
        "js/price-range.js",
        "js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js",
        "js/main.js"
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    ];
}
```

Can you please point out my mistake.

Comment: Are you supposed to have forward slashes on the yii string, and should it be followed by a comma?

Comment: @denmch
https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/doc/api/2.0/app-assets-appasset#$css-detail

Comment: So then does rhe extraneous comma throw it off?

Comment: @denmch
It does not. You can have a trailing comma if you'd like.

Comment: @denmch , you dont use trailing `/` with the source files as it creates problems when using `appendTimestamp` options when generating the links. see this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48236122/appendtimestamp-and-registerassetbundle/48240092#48240092)

Comment: @tnsaturday what are you getting instead? are you pointing the correct `AppAsset` file, as i dont see a complete namespace provided in above code, if it isnt just omitted adding code here, can you verify if the actual file is being called? try adding a syntax error in the source `AppAsset` class. or `print_r()` somethign inside the `init()` method.

Comment: @muhammad-omer-aslam both files have correct namespaces and use statements, I just had to omit it because otherwise stackoverflow won't let me post a question due to too much code.

Comment: ok and can you confirm the file is being called? because there isnt much here to point out any mistake nothing seems wrong here, that would prevent adding the scripts to the document.

Comment: @muhammad-omer-aslam Thx a lot for your help, I'll make an online sandbox files to show exactly what code is being executed in just ten minutes.

Comment: @muhammad-omer-aslam Seems like it was something related to beginBody() endBody() missing methods.

Comment: Yes that could have been the reason, thats why i was looking for more, glad it solves your problem